# keras model.fit() and TF tape.gradient() giving different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a model that I am building using the keras functional API. After defining it, I compile it with the SGD optimizer as follows.

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.05, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-3,clipnorm=1)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
model.fit(train_datagen, epochs=50,shuffle=True,verbose=True)
```

This works fine and my model converges as expected.

However, when I to implement the same exact functionality using TF's tape gradient, I consistently get NaN gradients which cause my weights to equate to NaN and subsequently my loss function value because NaN. Here is the code that I use:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.05, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-3,clipnorm=1)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

epochs = 50

for epoch in range(epochs):
        
    batch_list = list(range(len(train_datagen)))
    random.shuffle(batch_list)

    running_loss = 0
    
    for ii in batch_list:
        x,y_true = train_datagen[ii]
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = model(x, training=True)
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_true,y_pred)
            
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
        opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
        
        running_loss += loss_value
    
    print('Epoch',epoch,'Running Loss:',running_loss.numpy()/len(batch_list))
```

Is the code that I wrote equivalent to the Keras model.fit() functionality? For some reason, when I use the above code, I consistently get `NaN` gradients but with model.fit() it never happens.

Comment: Is the   "train_datagen"  in the first model the same in the second?

Comment: yeah it is - ended up finding the solution to this though. it's apparently a known TF bug in TF2.1 which they fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the class based loss, `MeanSquaredError`, requires some extra tinkering to get it working outside of the `.fit` method. Instead, use the functional one to make it easier. Just call it inside the training step like this.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = model(x, training=True)
    loss_value = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true,y_pred)
```